# Typescript JSON Path Type

Tags: typescript, generics, tuples, typescript-generics, jsonpath

I'm trying to build a few types so that I can define a generic function that

- takes an object and a JSON-path
  (arrays can be ignored for the moment)
- automatically deduce the correct return type
- **IDE-AutoComplete hints for all possible paths**

I've successfully managed to accomplish the first to bullets, however, I cannot get any autocomplete hints.

I've tried to build a working type that creates a union of all valid-paths.
But this is where I got stuck.

Here's what I got so far

```js
// helper types
type Length<T> = T extends { length: infer L } ? L : never;

type PopFront<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer U, ...infer R] ? U : never;
type Shift<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer U, ...infer R] ? R : never;

type Filter<T extends unknown[], U> = T extends [] ? [] : T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? F extends U ? Filter<R, T> : [F, ...Filter<R, U>] : never
type TupleIncludes<T extends unknown[], U> = Length<Filter<T, U>> extends Length<T> ? false : true
type StringIncludes<S extends string, D extends string> = S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? true : false; 

type Includes<T extends unknown[]|string, U> = T extends unknown[] ? TupleIncludes<T, U> : T extends string ? U extends string ? StringIncludes<T, U> : never : never
type Join<T extends unknown[], D extends string> = PopFront<T> extends string ? Length<T> extends 1 ? `${PopFront<T>}` : Shift<T> extends string[] ? `${PopFront<T>}${D}${Join<Shift<T>, D>}` : never : never; 

type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
    string extends S ? string[] :
        S extends '' ? [] :
            S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ?  [T, ...Split<U, D>] : [S];

// return type deduction from path
type NestedType<T, P extends string> = (
  Includes<P, '.'> extends true
    ? PopFront<Split<P, '.'>> extends keyof T
      ? NestedType<T[PopFront<Split<P, '.'>>], Join<Shift<Split<P, '.'>>, '.'>>
      : never
    : P extends keyof T ? T[P] : never
);

// Demo

const dictionary = {
  someProp: 123,
  nested: {
    moreProps: 333,
    deeper: {
      evenDeeper: {
        deepest: 'str'
      }
    },
    alsoDeeper: {
      randomProp: {
        anotherProp: 'yay'
      }
    }
  }
} as const;
type MyDict = typeof dictionary;

type Test1 = NestedType<MyDict, 'nested.alsoDeeper.randomProp.anotherProp'>; // = yay

const Fn = <T, P extends string>(dict: T, path: P): NestedType<T, P> => {
  // skip impl.
  return undefined as any;
};

const testFromFn = Fn(dictionary, 'nested.moreProps'); // = 333
```

The code above is all fine and well, now to the type I've tried to build,
which should give me all valid paths:

```js
// If you look at type "Debug" below, this surprisingly works.
// ...apart from the `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.`-error
type ValidPaths<T> = keyof T extends never ? never : ({
     [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never ? never : T[K] extends Record<string|number|symbol, unknown>
       ? K extends string ? `${K}.${ValidPaths<T[K]>}` | K : never
       : K
   })[keyof T];
type Debug = ValidPaths<MyDict>;

// So I also tried with Tuples.
type ValidPathTuples<T> = keyof T extends never ? never : ({
     [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never ? never : T[K] extends Record<string|number|symbol, unknown>
       ? [K, ...ValidPathTuples<T[K]>] | [K]
       : [K]
   })[keyof T];
// Which seems fine, too!
type DebugTuples = ValidPathTuples<MyDict>;
// But now, I cannot join them to path-strings
type DebugTuples1 = Join<ValidPathTuples<MyDict>, '.'>;
```

What exactly am I missing here, or am I on the wrong path?
Why exactly does the tuple version work, but the one using string-literal-templates doesn't?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsFMBsAdIE6gC4E94GcBQb6gDKQB2A5suADwAqAfKALyhWiQAeyxAJhqAN6jRiZcAC5QASyIAzRAVABfUAH45YopABuiANxYc6SKAAKAe1gAxBCaLJqLdlx4BXIgGsiJgO5EA2gF06RmY2DiJuUB9JGSQAVQAaUAA6ZKjZACU-ZVAY0DVNHX08AGVwcSlbYIcw5zcPb39ApntQ8MjpWXiklPakDKy03NB1LQRdQsNzcWgOBDsQx1AXdy9fPwSYxsqWnn8s3bEthbbo0HME5MTU3syVc2aFnNupmYo0hNpBnzOuxMnpxFe6xomTyI3GTCcsEEAEkiABjaBOTiQDBzKrhJZ1VZAhgEITkCh-F5UIF0ebVPGkAkfFRSACG0AwhjEyAQTkg4KKrMkJFhCKRKIoRXuFIw3NICQAIiLwmKEDzGsLyeEAAYAEl4VyY8g1kp1mp62XkKqyrPZg3pjMg2lAelwhj5iORqMOFMxK38AB85TycUEZTVlvUbhCoZBHQKXTiDgHQD7SFkcsqePGSFkufLSBHndRo0N8khQYhwQApEySNHbRa1D1rUDS5Nx8UkRqmCxWGzUMnolPNrKEKmUD6NgCMWXVvDblmsFRoxsGJTKs9jqd2KgnU47s-1eo1ZYri-KXalc5NRcL+ZGNrtBlARSh4lsSp7TczJClK+bgSwoF-r55sbCioq4gj+f7gc+VYAORQXsoHgQhf6QQsE5alQO76lqMTzioEQkj897QI+FCdJKwKfEUfhjCAoAIJAyBOAgRAoLeyKcE4cLIOI1igFIVgALagLAdLkOCAByKIcJwVAGLmxifm+jQABRgdmgpGAkUGJFB3ZVmaHLgSom4zkKD62BpoBaTpukLK4kCoCYUhMGBhmgBJYqQNJslUD4xmdoRxEWVZNDAgk+5EEKpRHgF5madpIVxdZLl-ueyViEYsZ2Q5TnMCoPlGCCl7FgAlNRYCSpA-EmHocLWGKoCcOInHcUQdIIKguK8GBGAmPxkBGFYsBiCOABMADMcRgeoHmcGIXXgVVdEDWYGBiGN62TeByKQPACBzclv75EQFU7Yg+2Ib+22YMgYhQXKUEHQoyXyJtf4Mj1J27edCEIHSYS9ctQ18I9v5-SY5CIIDt2oHSqAPYh8jPWBiOKHSPC1UQYq6PaoAALKoJKTXILi9qOQ1RMtW1qBjDjVCSWOjDuVJMnwBQ+OE5xmnTVJiTvSYn2IIkv3-fxgO8x4EMIIDOk2jRjAw6gNV1cT5jMYwckZY2qY0EpjWcQcCTCeQ6XFWITOeSzkAa4EdDzaANEYK44iwBI-FQokYF0QxTHVsiUiSJ5oBo0HRDU1g8hjBj9UcGK078aruKq7rFPWFTXOSZ5iSLf1g0YFBpX22AjDrWNehYDR0JOQ5TgCCYJiuEHxM4wARBVABGTgkM3oBtzAXgJOQ4gpoxsDyhgPLQB1ngmAgrgYB7NEXHSwkIMTfG9SgUCgCqlsSJjyB-VxIktRIPBsHCKLj1ok8NZAO0h5wQkmBg49tzfUSSI+kCJCqAC0iBWAQOCAAagycQnAjAiXAC6RoWUyaunCMMWQKgkEXiUnbP8PgADSe9QBwJyn4A42DMiNlQVkMhRCsEkJfGkSAtUECcAoKmT0RAnD8V7ggb0qB2EmGgAkd03gaAgxUDgrWfZ1waiwfIRIGpQFEQgVAl0xDTygE9KAHBqULpiCwS5eQxUfD4KYFRcE7dO64jkeAyB5BUTsyJjQMqd4TCgGhEHRkTjuSB08I+cAoZBDzxAWAhR5AqCQj8V2XEhiEE8DISggsgx0EHWwbgyJhCmDENjDEoqF4fJUNjLQ+hjDmGsPYYgLhPC+HViDEQIRF0VDYPOMkCxQTwAhLDEoqh5E1HEJBmIbpf49EGPsvA4xNEADqpQ4Q+KZJVHg-t1ADzrgAQhMZADuJBWl+PMYEqxLTQmClsZxex5cwAACEnDEzqAkFxcI-oS1AAAK3LMxCGglkBOKNuAX+qZsA41MesvZGAGagHChQJpOyNn7IJnYxK9igA)

Edit:

I just figured something out.

I changed my Join-type to this

```js
type Join<T extends unknown[], D extends string> = T extends string[]
  ? PopFront<T> extends string ? Length<T> extends 1 ? `${PopFront<T>}` : `${PopFront<T>}${D}${Join<Shift<T>, D>}` : never
  : never;
```

Now the `Join<ValidPathTuples, '.'>` produces the correct result.
The only thing done was to remove `Shift<T> extends string[] ? trueExpr : falseExpr;` and just use the removed `trueExpr`

I don't really understand what difference that made ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Wow, very impressive!! Did you manage to get this working for arrays too?

Comment: @johansenja 
Can be made to work without that much effort.

Here's a updated Playground  
https://1-3-3-7.dev/u/so1ts1play

I only made the `NestedTypeByTuple` work for this example.
`ValidPaths` and String-Literal based types are left as an exercise to the reader ;P

Additionally: You might want to check out this: https://behind.flatspot.pictures/advanced-typescript-cheatsheet-pt-1/

Comment: Nice cheat sheet! Though I couldn't get the first link to work :/

Comment: @johansenja link works for me.
Ouh well. Try another url shortener
bit dot ly/38bxkkR